# Evaluar los valores de una lista en una función

Tags: python, python-3.x

quisiera saber como puedo sacar los valores de una lista y que se evaluen en una función para que al final, al imprimir, me salga el resultado según el valor de la lista. Este es mi código:

```
import math

def f(x):
    return(0.39894*math.exp((-0.5)*x**2))


def sumariemann(): #Por la derecha (inferior) para evitar sobreestimaciones,
    a = -3.9
    b = [-3.09,-3.08,-3.07,-3.06,-3.05,-3.04,-3.03,-3.02,-3.01,-3,-2.99,-2.98,-2.97,-2.96,-2.95,-2.94,-2.93,-2.92,-2.91,-2.9,-2.89,-2.88,-2.87,-2.86,-2.85,-2.84,-2.83,-2.82,-2.81,-2.8,-2.79,-2.78,-2.77,-2.76,-2.75,-2.74,-2.73,-2.72,-2.71,-2.7,-2.69,-2.68,-2.67,-2.66,-2.65,-2.64,-2.63,-2.62,-2.61,-2.6,-2.59,-2.58,-2.57,-2.56,-2.55,-2.54,-2.53,-2.52,-2.51,-2.5,-2.49,-2.48,-2.47,-2.46,-2.45,-2.44,-2.43,-2.42,-2.41,-2.4,-2.39,-2.38,-2.37,-2.36,-2.35,-2.34,-2.33,-2.32,-2.31,-2.3,-2.29,-2.28,-2.27,-2.26,-2.25,-2.24,-2.23,-2.22,-2.21,-2.2,-2.19,-2.18,-2.17,-2.16,-2.15,-2.14,-2.13,-2.12,-2.11,-2.1,-2.09,-2.08,-2.07,-2.06,-2.05,-2.04,-2.03,-2.02,-2.01,-2,-1.99,-1.98,-1.97,-1.96,-1.95,-1.94,-1.93,-1.92,-1.91,-1.9,-1.89,-1.88,-1.87,-1.86,-1.85,-1.84,-1.83,-1.82,-1.81,-1.8,-1.79,-1.78,-1.77,-1.76,-1.75,-1.74,-1.73,-1.72,-1.71,-1.7,-1.69,-1.68,-1.67,-1.66,-1.65,-1.64,-1.63,-1.62,-1.61,-1.6,-1.59,-1.58,-1.57,-1.56,-1.55,-1.54,-1.53,-1.52,-1.51,-1.5,-1.49,-1.48,-1.47,-1.46,-1.45,-1.44,-1.43,-1.42,-1.41,-1.4,-1.39,-1.38,-1.37,-1.36,-1.35,-1.34,-1.33,-1.32,-1.31,-1.3,-1.29,-1.28,-1.27,-1.26,-1.25,-1.24,-1.23,-1.22,-1.21,-1.2,-1.19,-1.18,-1.17,-1.16,-1.15,-1.14,-1.13,-1.12,-1.11,-1.1,-1.09,-1.08,-1.07,-1.06,-1.05,-1.04,-1.03,-1.02,-1.01,-1,-0.99,-0.98,-0.97,-0.96,-0.95,-0.94,-0.93,-0.92,-0.91,-0.9,-0.89,-0.88,-0.87,-0.86,-0.85,-0.84,-0.83,-0.82,-0.81,-0.8,-0.79,-0.78,-0.77,-0.76,-0.75,-0.74,-0.73,-0.72,-0.71,-0.7,-0.69,-0.68,-0.67,-0.66,-0.65,-0.64,-0.63,-0.62,-0.61,-0.6,-0.59,-0.58,-0.57,-0.56,-0.55,-0.54,-0.53,-0.52,-0.51,-0.5,-0.49,-0.48,-0.47,-0.46,-0.45,-0.44,-0.43,-0.42,-0.41,-0.4,-0.39,-0.38,-0.37,-0.36,-0.35,-0.34,-0.33,-0.32,-0.31,-0.3,-0.29,-0.28,-0.27,-0.26,-0.25,-0.24,-0.23,-0.22,-0.21,-0.2,-0.19,-0.18,-0.17,-0.16,-0.15,-0.14,-0.13,-0.12,-0.11,-0.1,-0.09,-0.08,-0.07,-0.06,-0.05,-0.04,-0.03,-0.02,-0.01,0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.2,0.21,0.22,0.23,0.24,0.25,0.26,0.27,0.28,0.29,0.3,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.4,0.41,0.42,0.43,0.44,0.45,0.46,0.47,0.48,0.49,0.5,0.51,0.52,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.57,0.58,0.59,0.6,0.61,0.62,0.63,0.64,0.65,0.66,0.67,0.68,0.69,0.7,0.71,0.72,0.73,0.74,0.75,0.76,0.77,0.78,0.79,0.8,0.81,0.82,0.83,0.84,0.85,0.86,0.87,0.88,0.89,0.9,0.91,0.92,0.93,0.94,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99,1,1.01,1.02,1.03,1.04,1.05,1.06,1.07,1.08,1.09,1.1,1.11,1.12,1.13,1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17,1.18,1.19,1.2,1.21,1.22,1.23,1.24,1.25,1.26,1.27,1.28,1.29,1.3,1.31,1.32,1.33,1.34,1.35,1.36,1.37,1.38,1.39,1.4,1.41,1.42,1.43,1.44,1.45,1.46,1.47,1.48,1.49,1.5,1.51,1.52,1.53,1.54,1.55,1.56,1.57,1.58,1.59,1.6,1.61,1.62,1.63,1.64,1.65,1.66,1.67,1.68,1.69,1.7,1.71,1.72,1.73,1.74,1.75,1.76,1.77,1.78,1.79,1.8,1.81,1.82,1.83,1.84,1.85,1.86,1.87,1.88,1.89,1.9,1.91,1.92,1.93,1.94,1.95,1.96,1.97,1.98,1.99,2,2.01,2.02,2.03,2.04,2.05,2.06,2.07,2.08,2.09,2.1,2.11,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.15,2.16,2.17,2.18,2.19,2.2,2.21,2.22,2.23,2.24,2.25,2.26,2.27,2.28,2.29,2.3,2.31,2.32,2.33,2.34,2.35,2.36,2.37,2.38,2.39,2.4,2.41,2.42,2.43,2.44,2.45,2.46,2.47,2.48,2.49,2.5,2.51,2.52,2.53,2.54,2.55,2.56,2.57,2.58,2.59,2.6,2.61,2.62,2.63,2.64,2.65,2.66,2.67,2.68,2.69,2.7,2.71,2.72,2.73,2.74,2.75,2.76,2.77,2.78,2.79,2.8,2.81,2.82,2.83,2.84,2.85,2.86,2.87,2.88,2.89,2.9,2.91,2.92,2.93,2.94,2.95,2.96,2.97,2.98,2.99,3,3.01,3.02,3.03,3.04,3.05,3.06,3.07,3.08,3.09]
    
    n = int(input("¿En cuántos rectángulo dividirá la curva: "))
    Dx = (b - a)/n
    A=0

    for i in range(1,n):
        A += f(b-Dx*i)*Dx
    return (A)

print(sumariemann())
```

Contexto: se trata de una suma de Riemann por la derecha aplicada a la distribución Normal, por lo que a es el límite inferior de la integral y b es el límite superior de la integral. Por lo que prácticamente el programa estaría aproximando la probabilidad acumulada hasta b según los n rectángulos que el usuario desee. Por lo que quisiera al final, se imprima una especie de tabla con el límite b y su aproximación según n.

Comment: Hola Laura, cómo estás? creo que lo más sencillo sería usar la librería numpy, si creás un array de numpy podés evaluar la función en ese array  (quizá debas usar `numpy.exp()` no estoy seguro). por otra parte si no querés usar la librería, deberías agregar otro for fuera del primero que recorra los valores de b: `A =[]
for bb in b: 
  a = 0
  for i ...
    a+=..
  A.append( a)
..`

Comment: Muchas gracias^^

Comment: salió? sino lo pongo como respuesta

Comment: la verdad no he podido, es que soy principiante en esto, ¿tienes algún correo en el que te pueda contactar?

Comment: nombre apellido en gmail

Comment: uli...bus...@gm... así?

Comment: se sin ningún punto

Comment: ya te escribí al correo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la parte donde aparece el cálculo de `Dx` cambialo por:

`Dx = [(bb-a)/n for bb in b]`

En tu código reemplaza la parte desde  `A=0` por:

```
    A=[] #va a ser una lista ahora

    for j,bb in enumerate(b): bb va tomando cada uno de los valores de b
        a=0
        for i in range(1,n):
            a += f(bb-Dx[j]*i)*Dx[j]
        A.append(a)


print(sumariemann())
```

Comment: me sale el siguiente error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: en dónde? en que linea?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\MpE\Normal.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(sumariemann())
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\MpE\Normal.py", line 11, in sumariemann
    Dx = (b - a)/n
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: ay claro, el error está en la línea que dice `Dx = (b-a)/n` ya que b es una lista, reemplazala por `Dx = [(bb-a)/n for bb in b]` y luego dentro del for cada vez que aparezca `Dx` pon `Dx[j]` ahora lo corrijo en la respuesta

Comment: mirá que al momento de ejecuta me sale "None" (mil gracias por ayudar)

Comment: ahi te contesté al mail

Comment: listo, ya te contesté